# How to store intermediate results in plpgsql function?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `my_table` and a corresponding function:

```
create function my_function() returns setof my_table as
$$
    select my_table.*
    from   my_table
    where  ...;
$$
language sql stable;
```

Now I want to use that function in another `plpgsql` function. I want to store the results of `my_function()` so I can continue with the data. How is this done in PostgreSQL? I tried the following:

```
create function my_other_function() returns setof my_table as
$$
    declare
        results setof my_table;
    begin
        results := (select * from my_function());

        ...
    end;
$$
language plpgsql stable;
```

This however gives the error that `setof my_table` is an invalid type in `my_other_function()`, which is kinda odd, as it is a valid return type in `my_function()`?

Comment: This is generally not a very good approach, because the intermediately stored data may become large. You should use techniques from the relational paradigm (e.g. joins, sub-selects) instead. A materialized view might be another suitable approach, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array for that:

```
create function my_other_function() 
  returns setof my_table 
as
$$
declare
  results my_table[];
begin

  select array_agg(t)
    into results
  from my_function() t;

  return query 
    select *
    from unnest(results);
end;
$$
language plpgsql stable;
```